# Shiny local deployment error : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8

Tags: r, utf-8, shiny, encode

I am surprised to see a sudden error where my ShinyApp stopped working with an unknown error saying 'input string 1 is invalid UTF-8'. Even on yesterday, that App was working perfectly, however, stopped all sudden.

Below is the description of the error when I run `runApp()`

```
> runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3726
Warning: Error in sub: input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

My session info :

```
> library(shiny); sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1  R6_2.2.2        htmltools_0.3.6 Rcpp_0.12.12   
[5] digest_0.6.12   xtable_1.8-2    httpuv_1.3.5    mime_0.5
```

Have someone faced with similar error? Appreciate for any pointer on how to fix this error. I searched over net for a while for its solution, however didnt find any relevant.

Thanks for your time.

Thanks,

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by [replacing non UTF-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r) in my data. `validUTF8()` helped me identify non UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `includeHTML` by any chance?

I've had this issue when saving Microsoft Publisher documents as .htm files then slapping them into an app.

It looks like `includeHTML` enforces 'UTF-8' encoding:

```
> includeHTML
function (path) {
  lines <- readLines(path, warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
  return(HTML(paste8(lines, collapse = "\\r\\n")))
}
```

However my Windows 10 system default is 'ISO-8859-1'.

In Rstudio you can do **File > Save With Encoding > UTF-8** and everything seems to work. Otherwise you could override the `includeHTML` function to allow the encoding argument of `readLines` to be set.

Comment: Hi Hayden, I later observed that in my Shiny app, there was a peculiar string which was causing that error. I removed that particular string and replaced it with something more meaningful. Now it is working fine. Anyway thanks for your pointer. Regards,