# UTF-8 formatting problems in R

Tags: r, utf-8

I'm trying to transform a Markdown file to a .docx file with pandoc. Unfortunately it is bitterly and stubbornly complaining about its format not being "UTF-8":

[image]

When creating the Markdown file, I'm using text-data from an Excel file written in English. Two of the columns are coded in an "unknown" format according to "Encoding" as per [How to identify/delete non-UTF-8 characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r). Please see example vector for one of the columns (with data categories) below:

```
exampleVector
 [1] "other wards"  "organisation" "other wards"  "Trystview"    "break"        "other wards" 
 [7] "Trystview"    "other"        "break"        "other"  

exampleVector %>% Encoding()
 [1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"

exampleVector %>% dput()
c("other wards", "organisation", "other wards", "Trystview", 
"break", "other wards", "Trystview", "other", "break", "other"
)
```

I've tried all suggestions on [How to identify/delete non-UTF-8 characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r) and [Force character vector encoding from "unknown" to "UTF-8" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r) without success, including the commands in the "stringi" library to transform the above vector to "UTF-8" format. I'm not sure what I'm missing and am wondering why the format of a fairly mundane Excel file is posing such challenges for pandoc. I used read_excel from the "readxl" library to import Excel data. Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: did you try changing the default encoding in Tools >> Global Options to UTF-8 and then saving the Markdown file?

Comment: Your error points you towards two line with invalid characters, lines 45 and 313 - can you try to replace those characters? It might be due to a copy-paste.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram: Thanks for your comment. I'm using RStudio version 1.2.5042. I couldn't find any references to UTF-8 under Tools --> Global Options. Do you mean somewhere under Tools --> Global Options --> Code? I can't find it there, either ... Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Yozef Tools --> Global Options --> Code --> under saving tab

Comment: @mhh: Thanks for your comment. The Markdown file looks in Notepad pristine and clear. I can't see any dodgy characters there. I deleted the first couple of hundred characters for a laugh and tried pandoc then. Now the error message says the (new) file has invalid UTF-8 characters at position 255. I suspect there are a number of those offending characters in the file, however they don't seem to be obviously or visually identifiable with Notepad.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram: I've found the option above now and changed it to UTF-8. I still have the same error message as before. No changes when switching off RStudio and re-starting it ...

Comment: @Yozef did yuo open the Rmd file and saved it once again? Meanwhile, I'll look for the other possible solution.

Comment: Has anyone tried what `Encoding` returns with the exampleVector above. Do you get "unknown", too?

Comment: @Mohanasundaram: I'm not sure how to open and save the .md file once again. I'm not very good with Markdown. I had my code save a Markdown file with a different name and tried to use `pandoc` on that. Same result as above ...

Comment: When you say Notepad, are you implying that you are editing this file in Notepad, or RStudio?

Comment: @mhh: The Markdown file is created by an R code. I just visualised its contents with NotePad, didn't create the Markdown file with NotePad.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my frustrations! I only had to add the parameter `encoding = "UTF-8"` to the lines defining the creation of the Markdown file in the R code:

```
fileConn <- file("C:/projects/use of time/report1.md", encoding = "UTF-8")
close(fileConn)
```