# Splitting a column into date/time in tidyverse

Tags: r, date, split, tidyverse

I acknowledge that there are multiple similar questions, but I did not find so far an answer, which works for me, maybe because of AM/PM. I would like not to remove the latter.

I have a column `Trip Start Timestamp`, which looks like

```
12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM
12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM
12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM
```

I am trying to remove AM/PM and split into two variables `Start date` and `Start time`.

Ideal output:

```
Start date Start time
12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM
```

I would like to read it as time series.

My best guess so far

```
Date <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(taxi_2020$`Trip Start Timestamp`, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:S")), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
Time <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(taxi_2020$`Trip Start Timestamp`, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:S")), format = "%H:%M:S")
head(Date)
head(Time)
```

Gives me

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

**Update**

It looks like columns with time and date has some problems with format.

`dput` can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZIDeKn-suIsjgG_V5g2KL_VHogKju3X51voqEkbI-U8/edit?usp=sharing)

So far the solution by @Ronak Shah works. Technically I finally separated the data, but probably identified another problem with [UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged this with `tidyverse`, here's a simple approach with `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(mdy_hms(`Trip Start Timestamp`)), 
         Time = format(mdy_hms(`Trip Start Timestamp`), "%I:%M:%S %p"))
#    Trip Start Timestamp       Date        Time
#1 12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM 2019-12-01 12:30:00 AM
#2 12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM 2019-12-01 12:31:00 AM
#3 12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM 2019-12-01 12:32:00 AM
```

**Example Data**

```
data <- structure(list(`Trip Start Timestamp` = c("12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM", 
"12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM", "12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were the first and in tidyverse, so I will accept your answer.

Comment: Error: Column `Time` must be length 4137294 (the number of rows) or one, not 3.

Comment: the code now works, but the initial column `Trip Start Timestamp` is NA now <S3: POSIXct> and new columns also NA. Date as <date> NA and Time as character NA

Comment: I wonder if there is some sort of factor problem. Can you [edit] your post with the output of `dput(taxi_2020[1:20,])`? It’s really late, so I’ll take a look tomorrow if someone else can’t help you.

Comment: Done, it is too big. I put on google drive. Definitely some formatting problem, I cannot read it in Python too, gives me an error with some characters. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have this error - Error in gsub(reg$alpha_exact[["A"]], "%A", x, ignore.case = T, perl = T) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

## tidyverse

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(
    ## option 1
    psx = as.POSIXct(V1, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC"), 
    Date = format(psx, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), 
    Time = format(psx, format = "%I:%M:%S %p"), 
    ## option 2
    Date2 = sub("\\s.*", "", V1), 
    Time2 = sub("^\\S*\\s", "", V1)
  )
#                        V1                 psx       Date        Time      Date2        Time2
# 1  12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM 2019-12-01 12:30:00 12/01/2019 12:30:00 PM 12/01/2019  12:30:00 AM
# 2  12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM 2019-12-01 12:31:00 12/01/2019 12:31:00 PM 12/01/2019  12:31:00 AM
# 3 12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM  2019-12-01 12:32:00 12/01/2019 12:32:00 PM 12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- read.table(header = FALSE, text = "
12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM
12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM
12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM ", sep = "|")
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that keeping the output in the format that you have shown would return columns as characters/factors.

You can split the data on whitespace using `tidyr::separate`

```
tidyr::separate(data, `Trip Start Timestamp`, c('Start Date', 'Start Time'), 
                       sep = ' ', extra = 'merge')

#  Start Date  Start Time
#1 12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM
#2 12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM
#3 12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM
```

Similarly, you can use `extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(data, `Trip Start Timestamp`, c('Start Date', 'Start Time'), 
               regex = '(.*?)\\s(.*)')
```

Comment: But the first code returns columns as characters will all NAs. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rookie Your data must be different then. I am using Ian's data. Can you test it on that data?

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. Error: Column `Time` must be length 4137294 (the number of rows) or one, not 3

Comment: @Rookie In your `dput` I think the relevant part is only `structure(list(\`Trip Start Timestamp\` = c("12/01/2019 12:15:00 AM", 
"12/01/2019 12:15:00 AM", "12/01/2019 12:15:00 AM"), \`Trip End Timestamp\` = c("12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM", 
"12/01/2019 12:15:00 AM", "12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))` . Rest all doesn't get picked up ? And for this data my answer works fine for me.

Comment: apologize! Update to 20 rows

Comment: I get this error, using Ian's code now - Error in gsub(reg$alpha_exact[["A"]], "%A", x, ignore.case = T, perl = T) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8

Comment: @Rookie My answer still works fine on your updated data for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did, I finally managed to split the data! But it looks like I have another problem with UTF-8. See the updated question. I will dig into it! Appreciate your help. Not sure why tidyverse solutions failed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` to split

```
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(data[[1]],
        "(?<=[0-9]) (?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE))
names(out) <- c('Start Date', 'Start Time')
out
#  Start Date  Start Time
#1 12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM
#2 12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM
#3 12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(`Trip Start Timestamp` = c("12/01/2019 12:30:00 AM", 
"12/01/2019 12:31:00 AM", "12/01/2019 12:32:00 AM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: But it gives me Error in data[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @Rookie Can you check the `str(yourdata)`.  I assume it is a `data.frame` or `tibble` as it should work with those structures

Comment: tibble [4,137,294 x 21] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Start Date                : chr [1:4137294] "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" ...
 $ Start Time                : chr [1:4137294] "12:15:00 AM" "12:15:00 AM" "12:15:00 AM" "12:15:00 AM" ...
 $ End Date                  : chr [1:4137294] "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" "12/01/2019" ...
 $ End Time                  : chr [1:4137294] "12:30:00 AM" "12:15:00 AM" "12:30:00 AM" "12:30:00 AM" ...

Comment: @Rookie Are you splitting on "Start Time"?  In that case use `strsplit(data[["Start Time"]], ...`

Comment: @Rookie Based on the image, The "Trip End Timestamp" is 3rd column.  So, you may need `strsplit(taxi_2020_test[["Trip End Timestamp"]], ...`

Comment: Sorry, did not get what you mean, I separated into Start Date and Start Time already as Ronak suggested above

Comment: @Rookie  I meant that the `strsplit(data[[1]]` is based on the assumption that it is the first column, if it is not, then change it to the index of the column or the actual column name