# Fix (convert/drop) invalid UTF-8 characters in R

Tags: r, string, utf-8, character

I have an issue with UTF-8 coding in a huge dataframe (millions of rows).
I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r), but I did not fix the issue.

My column (character) is very simple:

```
Start date
12/01/2019
12/01/2019
12/02/2019
```

[image]

I am trying to convert into date

```
taxi_2020_test$`Start Date` <- mdy(taxi_2020_test$`Start Date`)
```

and get this

```
Error in gsub(reg$alpha_exact[["A"]], "%A", x, ignore.case = T, perl = T) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

It is 100% an issue with UTF-8, because in Python I cannot even import this dataset into Jupyter, it gives me an error, again mentioning UTF-8.

How to fix or at least to drop this? I have millions of rows and if it is a small number of bad rows, I am ok with it.

Comment: Maybe you can find the lines to exclude with `grepl("[^0-9/ ]", taxi_2020_test$"Start Date")`

Comment: @GKi, thanks for your suggestion! Did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe then try `grep("^\\d+/\\d+/\\d+$", taxi_2020_test$"Start Date")` to find lines to use.

Comment: Did find the actual bad character(s) in your `start_date` column?

Comment: I guess so, if I cannot convert it

Comment: @GKi, thanks, will try tomorrow!