# R: How to deal with replacement character � that doesn't want to disappear

Tags: r, dataframe, special-characters, utf

I have a big data frame `main_df` with `company_names` and several `variables`. Some of the `company_names` are misspelled, have typos, or need to be changed otherwise. Therefore, I am creating a `vector` of unique names, using:

```
unique_names <- unique(levels(as.factor(main_df$company_name)))
```

This gives me a `vector` that looks something like this when seen from the view window `view(unique_names):`

```
V1:
Cosmonize Bulgaria Inc.
Crown One Foundation
Institut f�r Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik
```

Suppose, for instance, that `Crown One Foundation` changed its name to `Crown Two Foundation`. In this case, I would hard code the change in `main_df` for all instances:

```
main_df$company_name[which(main_df$company_name == "Crown One Foundation")] <- "Crown Two Foundation"
```

This approach has worked well for all entries except the ones that show a `replacement character`, like `Institut f�r Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik.`

I've tried copying the entry from the view window:

```
main_df$company_name[which(main_df$company_name == "Institut f�r Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik")] <- "Institut fur Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik"
```

I've also tried to slice out the appropriate cell and used the result: `unique_names[100]`:

```
main_df$company_name[which(main_df$company_name == "Institut f\xfcr Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik")] <- "Institut fur Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik"
```

Neither approach worked. When I refresh `unique_names <- unique(levels(as.factor(main_df$company_name)))` nothing changes. Interestingly, when I search for `Institute` in the search window of the `view window`, the one in question does not appear.

Another idea I had was to work with `Encoded`. I used `Encoding(unique_names[100]` to find that it is `UTF-8`. Using `Encoding(unique_names[100] <- 'latin1'` changed the entry in the view window to `Institut für Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik`.

However, upon refreshing the unique entries using `unique_names <- unique(levels(as.factor(main_df$company_name)))`, the entry is not updated.

Even then,
`main_df$company_name[which(main_df$company_name == "Institut für Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik")] <- "Institut fur Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik"`
doesn't lead to a change either (removing the umlaut here).

Am I looking at this the wrong way? I know there is a lot of hard coding and I've changed all entries besides the ones with the `replacement character`. Therefore, I don't want to change the `Encoded` properties for the entire vector but rather change these few dozen entries manually.

Thanks a lot in advance. I don't have a package preference and would appreciate any help.

Edit: Upon request, here is the part of the output for `dput(unique_names)`:

```
c("Aalborg University", "Aalto University", "Aarhus University", "ACDVE", "Aero LLC", "AgilitySpaceCorp", "Air Force Research Laboratory (AFRL), "Airbus")
```

Here is `dput(head(main_df$company_name))`:

```
c("Aalborg University", "Aalborg University", "Aalborg University", "Aalborg University", "Aalborg University", "Aalborg University")
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights @27ϕ9! I've added the requested lines to the question.

Comment: Update: I managed to solve the issue by using a combination of startsWith and endsWith. Cumbersome but effective cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Have you tried substituting the one character in question using `gsub`and regular expression AND converting to character type?

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Institut f�r Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik", "Aarhus University", "ACDVE", "Aero LLC", "AgilitySpaceCorp", "Air Force Research Laboratory (AFRL)", "Airbus"))
```

Solution:

```
gsub("�","ü",as.character(df$Name))
```

Result:

```
[1] "Institut für Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik" "Aarhus University"                      "ACDVE"                                 
[4] "Aero LLC"                               "AgilitySpaceCorp"                       "Air Force Research Laboratory (AFRL)"  
[7] "Airbus"
```

My hunch is that, if you have multiple such special cases, you should convert the whole names set to character:

```
df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)
```

This would enable you to search the dataframe for cases where you have non-ASCII characters using this regex:

```
df[grepl("[^ -~]", df$Name),]
[1] "Institut f�r Luft-und Raumfahrttechnik"
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Much of the solution has to do with type conversion to character!

Comment: Very helpful, Chris! I appreciate it!

Comment: If it helped answer your question, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

the data was probably imported using incompatible codesets.
eg. reading ISO-8859-5(Cyrillic) texts using us-ascii.

If you can re-import the original dataset, that will probably give you a cleaner thus better dataset to work in future.

if you need to work with what you have, I found this link to be a great starting point:
[How to identify/delete non-UTF-8 characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291287/how-to-identify-delete-non-utf-8-characters-in-r)